# IndexError: index 201850347 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 201837124 while using unstack operation for large dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement user-user collaborative filtering algorithm for my project. The code below works for very small dataset but while running it on the yelp dataset (1 M users 200k products) it gives an index error on the line where unstack is used. It reads and prints the huge dataset correctly but doesn't unstack it. Input is a dataset having users, products and associated ratings. Output must be the predictions computed.

I found many other questions on stackoverflow addressing this issue but they were not related to `unstack` operation of Python. I tried alternatives like not using `unstack` and doing all operations using `groupby` alone but it's not feasible. I am clueless how to sort this out.

```
import pandas as pd;
from math import *;

df = pd.read_csv('preprocessed.csv', names    ['users','Products','stars'],low_memory=False)
s = df.groupby(['users', 'Products']).sum()
m = s.unstack(fill_value=0.0)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
stars
Products product1 product2 product3
users
user1         1.0      0.0      4.0
user2         1.0      3.0      0.0
user3         1.0      0.0      0.0
user4         0.0      0.0      3.0


Predicted ratings
     stars
Products product1  product2  product3
users
user1         1.0  0.115504  4.000000
user2         1.0  3.000000  1.489822
user3         1.0  0.478533  0.521467
user4         1.5  0.500000  3.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you did when I unstacked a big groupby series. The problem comes from not having enough memory. So the best solution is to use a larger RAM machine to run your computation.

Comment: Exactly! I reduced my data size and the problem disappeared!